# Loading Google Map only when <a></a> is clicked

Tags: ajax, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to load a google map when a link is clicked on in my footer. However, I only want to load it when this link is clicked, I do not want it slowly load times for the main content in case the user does not wish to see the map. Any ideas on how to only load google maps when a link is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject `<script>` to the `document` to load Google Maps when `<a>` is clicked. Add a parameter `callback` to the URL and Google Maps will will call the Javascript function after loading :

```html
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize'>
</script>
```